# How to detect image link coordinate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a  question about position the div in a image map link

I have a image that contains multiple links

I want to position a single div on top of the image link.

```
<img id='project' src='test.png' USEMAP = '#test1'/>

<map name='test1'>
    <area class='btn' shape="rect" coords="36,20,55,34" href="#"/>
    <area class='btn' shape="rect" coords="18,37,35,56" href="#"/>
    <area class='btn' shape="rect" coords="54,38,72,56" href="#"/>
    <area class='btn' shape="rect" coords="31,61,57,75" href="#"/>
</map>
```

How do I find the right coordinate on the map and place a div on top of it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Easiest is just wrap the img in a div, then use absolute positioning/z-indexing to place your other div.

Comment: ya but I need it to be responsive for ipad. can it be done with absolute position?

Comment: You want a div that overlays the WHOLE map? or just one particular hotspot created by the map?

Comment: I have a div that will overlay the WHOLE map.